# How to Create and Next Button in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to create a Next button to route to the next page, but I only want it to go to the page if I answer a question as yes It can go to the next page but skip a part if the answer is no. If any of this make sense. I can further explain.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'', redirectTo:'home',pathMatch: "full"},
{path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path:'veteran', component: VeteranComponent},
{path:'veteran-snap', component: VeteranSnapComponent},
{path:'almost', component: AlmostComponent},
{path:'signature', component: SignatureComponent}
];
```

These are my routes.

Comment: You might want to look at https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate and https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the template

```
<input type="checkbox" #question name="quesiton1">
<button (click)="navigateIfYes(question.checked)">Go Next</button>
```

in the component

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigateIfYes(value: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(!!value ? VALUE_CHECKED_PAGE : VALUE_UNCHECKED_PAGE).catch(console.error);
}
```

This is a very basic example but the question is too generic to give an in depth answer

Comment: So I'm trying to make a WOTC 9061 Form basically online. So say if I ask If you received SNAP benefits ? You answer no i want to go to the next section.  If Yes we answer the next question of that section.  @giacomoto

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope it feet your needs

Comment: Thanks That's awesome okay what about if it's no? How do I get to the next section?

Comment: You decide the routing on the value of `value`.
You just have to replace `VALUE_CHECKED_PAGE` and `VALUE_UNCHECKED_PAGE` with the real paths. First one will route you to the YES page, next one to the NO section

Comment: How do I pass my radio buttons value to the navigate function?

Comment: How do I pass my radio buttons value to the navigate function? @giacomoto

Comment: What does it mean? You want to pass more values to the `navigateIfYes` function?
If you have jun one radio for page, the solutionm above will be fine, if you have multple inputs i sugest you to use the reactive form https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I get a error saying I need Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. I get this when I navigateIfYes(question.checked-> This part)

Comment: just change `navigateIfYes(value: string)` to `navigateIfYes(value: boolean)`

Comment: I do have a question can you explain the parameters in each function I just want to understand

Comment: How can I get required error trap for this before I go to the next page.